# mudar texto de um fileupload asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload, webdesign

Tem como mudar o texto que está dentro do FileUpload?

Queria mudar o texto "Nenhum ficheiro selecionado"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem como mudar essa mensagem o texto dentro do `input`, cada navegador renderiza o elemento do seu jeito, mas há como usar algum *workaround* para resolver. Uma alternativa é adicionar um label próprio que sobreponha do original, permitindo usar qualquer texto que deseje:

```js
function fileChange() {
  var e = document.getElementById('file');
  if(e.value == "")
  {
      fileLabel.innerHTML = "Nenhum arquivo selecionado";
  }
  else
  {
      var theSplit = e.value.split('\\');
      fileLabel.innerHTML = theSplit[theSplit.length-1];
  }

}

fileChange();
```

```css
input[type=file]{
    color:transparent;
}

#fileLabel {
  margin-left: -160px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type='file' title="Selecione um arquivo" id="file" onchange="fileChange()" >
   <label id="fileLabel">Nenhum arquivo selecionado</label>
 </div>
```

Comment: podia por o inicio em vb? é porque está a dar erro no theSplit

Comment: mas essa parte é `Javascript` não pode ser executado em `VB` :) essa parte deve estar na página (vbhtml, html, aspx, ascx, etc) ou num arquivo `.js`

Comment: o div coloca-se por baixo do FileUpload?

Comment: na verdade o FileUpload fica dentro da div, mas pode fazer isso até sem essa div também

Comment: funcionou , só que copiou e agora existem dois itens de upload iguais

Comment: não entendi, o código não irá duplicar o `input`, tem que ter somente um no `div`.. duplicou o input ou só o label que mostra a mensagem?

Comment: duplicou o quadrado onde se colocam as coisas. Ficaram dois, mas eu fiz o que me disse do ( " input[type=file]{
    color:transparent;
} " ) e resolvi o meu problema